# PostgreSQL Error: unexpected file found in temporary-files directory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-11, docker

PostgreSQL 11.2 has been running properly inside a Docker container until I did a `docker-compose up` to start a new container for another app, then accidentally press Ctrl+C, which killed all the running containers including the one containing PostgreSQL named `timescaledb`.

When I tried to start PostgreSQL again using the command `docker-compose up -d`, the docker log files show the following messages, including the errors

> unexpected file found in temporary-files directory

and

> database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-02-13 03:13:42 UTC

Do we need to do anything to the unexpected temporary files?

```
timescaledb | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
timescaledb | 
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.031 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.031 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.121 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0002545c0000006c"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00a5e39600002f2e"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden003e9e9e00001e8f"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0055488100002335"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden000ccab3000003ff"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0026501600001d7b"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0024760b00001564"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden000f30a300000a22"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden012cff9800007536"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden000cc3d7000003fc"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0077b46d00002a6f"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden012cf80d0000751b"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden003e811d00001e2e"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00247e1300001572"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden000e6df70000079c"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0054f16200002232"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0024e33300001688"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden007732a4000029cd"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0024bdd6000015f5"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden002495d2000015c4"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden015d68f900009445"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0021626800000de1"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00772fc3000029c0"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0003be5e0000011f"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0003ad4e0000010e"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden003e93f200001e80"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00232856000010b0"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00553d8600002316"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden000e1f1a000006b2"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0024687600001539"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00047afb00000145"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00a5b20900002ecc"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00772faf000029bf"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0126e6c60000737f"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden012cea2b00007503"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0024a136000015d5"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden007729f8000029ac"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden012cf4e600007509"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0024acab000015ea"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.271 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00262e8e00001ccc"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.272 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden003e819c00001e33"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.272 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00223d2d00000f98"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0055488300002331"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0126af680000734f"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0054428f00002107"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00225fe400000fa3"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0025c6e300001aaa"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden012cc38e000074df"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden00773a02000029d6"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden003e838700001e35"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden0024a52f000015e5"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden000e053c0000069d"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden000cdf3f0000040d"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden002647ee00001d5f"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  unexpected file found in temporary-files directory: "base/pgsql_tmp/.fuse_hidden003e9f1b00001e90"
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:18:28.699 UTC [20] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-02-13 03:13:42 UTC
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:23:32.981 UTC [20] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:23:34.497 UTC [20] LOG:  redo starts at A7/76B84360
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:23:34.497 UTC [20] LOG:  invalid record length at A7/76B84440: wanted 24, got 0
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:23:34.497 UTC [20] LOG:  redo done at A7/76B84408
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:23:37.617 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
timescaledb | 2020-02-13 06:23:37.622 UTC [26] LOG:  TimescaleDB background worker launcher connected to shared catalogs
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make sure that there is no query running on the database currently that may be using a temporary file, it is safe to remove these leftovers.